# How to globalize ASP.NET MVC views (decimal separators in particular)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I'm working with the [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) sample [application](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html) and arrived at the section which deals with the Virtual Earth map. The application stores some values for the longitude and latitude. Unfortunately on my system floating point numbers are stored with a comma as the decimal separator, not a dot like in the US. So if I have a latitude of 47.64 it's retrieved and displayed as 47,64. Because that value is passed in a function call to the Virtual Earth API it fails at that point (e.g. JavaScript API expects *47.64, -122.13*, but gets *47,64, -122,13*).

I need to make sure that the application always uses dots. In a WebForms app I would have a common class which overrides the `System.Web.UI.Page.InitializeCulture()` method and I would be inheriting my pages from that class.

I am not sure about how to do the same with MVC. Do I need a customized `ViewPage` or something? Is there an **easy** way to solve this? Examples?

Comment: It appears that this is already logged as a bug: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=2616

Comment: Hm. Maybe it's a bug? I added <globalization/> to my web.config to make sure the culture is set to en-US application wide, but it did not help at all, only after that I posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because setting `<globalization/>` to en-US did not help at all I decided to create a custom class which initializes the proper culture settings and make sure that all views which require this behavior are inherited from my custom class.

**NerdDinnerViewPage.cs:**

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NerdDinner.Views
{
    public class NerdDinnerViewPage<T> : ViewPage<T> where T : class
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            base.InitializeCulture();

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="NerdDinner.Views.NerdDinnerViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel>" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Danish developer and was facing exactly the same problem. I found a working solution which has been kindly described by Kristof Neirynck on his dev blog:

[Custom Model Binder](http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/07/30/custom-model-binder-to-avoid-decimal-separator-problems/)

Best regards, Finn Vilsbaek

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> on my system floating point numbers are stored with a comma as the decimal separator

I assume you mean that they are *formatted* with a comma, floating point numbers are stored as `float`.

Whilst you can tackle the formatting issue by setting Cultures the "real" fix is to change the code. OK, it's not your code so maybe you don't want to do that on this occassion, but for general reference you need to ensure that when formatting floats or anything else you use the appropriate culture. In the case of fomatting a number for use by an API you would use the InvariantCulture.

I.e. use `foo.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of `foo.ToString()` and likewise when using string.Format(...).

**Edit** I've just taken a look at the NerdDinner code and have realised that this error is in the Javascript not in C#, so my code above isn't going to help. I don't know if it is possible to format numbers in Javascript, but the real solution I think is to fix the model code to return a correctly formatted string.

**Edit 2** I'd suggest you try the following:
In the `SearchController.cs` change the `Latitude` and `Longitude` in `JsonDinner` to `strings`. i.e.

```
public class JsonDinner {
    public int      DinnerID    { get; set; }
    public string   Title       { get; set; }
    public string   Latitude    { get; set; }
    public string   Longitude   { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }
    public int      RSVPCount   { get; set; }
}
```

Then scroll down to the SearchByLocation method and change the Lat/Long lines to format the strings correctly for JavaScript:

```
Latitude = dinner.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
Longitude = dinner.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

This should mean that you do not need the fix you put in, and should fix your other question... where I will leave a comment. Hope this helps, I haven't fully tested is as I am not in your locale, but it certainly appears to work.

Comment: I am in Chapter 11 of that book. Haven't seen that JsonDinner class yet. :) Thanks for the effort, Steve, I will check it out soon (and will let you know)!

Comment: I worked until the "Integrating the Map with Create and Edit Forms" section and that's where it breaks. You probably looked at the SVN version and it may be different code. I am just following the book writing it / pasting myself.

Comment: Yeah, my fix only gets you a little further I'm afraid... the problem is that the VE Javascript just can't deal with comma separators - either passed in or retrieved. You can fix the issue of passing them in using my fix, but when you try and save a form the posted back data contains "." separators again and can't be parsed by the repository:-(

Comment: Probably you worded it in a better way, but that's essentially what I was trying to say from the very beginning. I still have no clue why <globalization /> tag in web.config does not fix it, though. I would expect it to work just like in WebForms app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simple quickfix in the TemplateEditor. My application is only using swedish (comma as decimal separator) so it's a single string.Replace but you could of course make it aware of multiple cultures.

In my Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.ascx:

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on the JavaScript-side instead, making sure that what is passed in to the map-library is using points (.), and what is populated back into the text boxes are using commas (,). Obviously, this is not meant for localization, but a quick fix.

**Map.js** in callbackForLocation:

```
//If we've found exactly one place, that's our address.
if (points.length === 1) {
    $("#Latitude").val(points[0].Latitude.toString().replace('.', ','));
    $("#Longitude").val(points[0].Longitude.toString().replace('.', ','));
}
```

**Map.ascx** in the jquery-ready():

```
    var latitude = <%=Model.Latitude.ToString().Replace(',', '.')%>;
    var longitude = <%=Model.Longitude.ToString().Replace(',', '.')%>;
```