# MVC3 edit for decimal fields and localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, number-formatting

My locale uses a comma `,`, and not a dot `.` for decimal separator.

In MVC3, when I open an Edit view where the decimal values are shown with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDecimalVal)
```

the value is shown correctly.

When I enter value with comma, I get error "Value is not a number" and if I enter value with dot, I get no error, but actually no value is saved.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting around with this by tweaking your validation logic has been already explained so here is a different approach.

Put the below code inside your web.config file under the `<system.web>` node if you would like to set the culture to `en`. It will take care of decimal delimiter:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />
```

I am not sure but for `DateTime`, you are still bound to your server's locale.

Comment: Thanks, this took care of both datetime and number formats (but forced them for en locale)

Comment: @bzamfir right. What I call this approach is a temporary fix. The permanent fix would to configure your server locales.

Comment: how in the world is this a solution - forcing the culture to English?

Comment: @gangelo when the end user doesn't care about the culture specific value, I am pretty darn sure this is a pretty darn good solution!

Comment: That's absolutely awesome. You saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

[This blog post](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator) recommends overriding the default jQuery validate number and range rules in order to enable client-side support of the comma decimal separator.

> To fix these problems, we can take the default implementation from the
>   jquery.validate.js file for the range() and number() functions. We
>   then create another .js file (say jQueryFixes.js), in which we
>   override these default functions with ones that contain support for
>   the comma as a decimal separator. The contents of the file should be
>   something like this:

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
}

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

Comment: Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: I mean, what about the handling of different decimal values in different cultures? Of couse I just want to store the values in one culture but I want to give the visitor of the webpage the chance to put in and validate decimal values in his culture.

Comment: @Christoph Brückmann, I'm a bit late to the party but this solution works. In french, it accepts $140,44 and in english it accepts $140.44.