# How to bind nullable decimal values

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm having problems with ASP.NET Core MVC and `decimal?` value.

I have the following view model:

```
 public class BlobViewModel
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? DecimalValue { get; set; }
 }
```

And the following input element in my view

```
<input asp-for="DecimalValue" class="form-control" />
```

When I enter a decimal value, e.g. "68.5" or "68,5" and tab out of the input element, I get the following error:

> The value '68.5' is not valid for DecimalValue.

I have tried with the `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` attribute above the property, but I can't seem to get the binding to work. The other properties binds as expected.

Does anyone have an idea for how I accomplish this?

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce this in a basic .Net Core (RTM) project.

Comment: There is a solution provided by ASP.NET Core for Globalization.
Need to add some settings in the Startup.cs in the methods ConfigureServices and Configure
Check out this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get occurs if you local Windows settings isn't set to US localization and you are using the default `asp.net` template `jquery` validation to validate decimal values. The errors should occur irrespective if your decimals are `nullable` or not

In `ASP.NET Core` I don't think you can  force the localization to US in the `web.config` as you get in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101589/mvc3-edit-for-decimal-fields-and-localization.) answer in the same way you can for `ASP.NET MVC5` and earlier, so you will have to add javascript to override the `jquery.validate.js` as mentioned as an answer to the same question.

create a `js` file called `validationlocalization` and put it in your `wwwroot\js` folder with the following contents

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
}

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

In the `cshtml` pages that require decimal validation add a reference to the `javascript` file to your scripts section. Make sure it is added after an reference to the existing `_ValidationScriptsPartial.`

```
@section Scripts {

     ...

     <script src="~/js/validationlocalization.js"></script>
```

[More detail](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator) on this workaround

Comment: Thanks a million. This was exactly what was needed :-)