# Strange issue about double numbers with commas

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a field in db named 'loss' which is of type float.

Here is how I save it in db:

```
[HttpPost]
public int SaveLoss(float loss)
{
   var t = (from x in db.tblTest
            where x.id == 8
            select x).First();
   t.loss = loss; //also tried t.loss = loss / 1;
   db.SaveChanges(); //entity framework
 }
```

This is how I always work and in all the other tables it works fine.

I enter the loss via a textbox and here is the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test/SaveLoss",
    data: {
        loss: parseFloat($('#myTextbox').val().replace(',', '.'))
    }
    ....
```

If in the textbox I enter 66.55, everything works great. If in the textbox I enter 66,55, the value stored in db is 6655. This issue doesn't happen on my computer. When I publish the application on server, it occurs. Why is this annoying issue happening and how to fix it?

Fiddler says that 66.55 is input parameter of SaveLoss.

Comment: why not pass the `string` value via ajax and handle the conversion to `float` on the server side? Also, use `F12` or Fiddler to see what is being sent to the server. Or debug in VS an check what the value of `loss` is.

Comment: @rob I would change the "Or" to "And"; need to know what the value is in three places: the browser, the http request, and the server.

Comment: Is typeof(t.loss) is float?

Comment: @rob I tried that and the same issue occurs. Fiddler says that 66.55 is input parameter of SaveLoss.

Comment: @MarcGravell The value in Fiddler is 66.55, The value in Chrome console is 66.55.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like either the browser or server has a different number format, perhaps it is running in a culture where ',' is used as a decimal separator and '.' as a thousands separator.

You could try setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` after starting the server or before running the database query.

Comment: +1 Was thinking along the same lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793459/how-to-set-decimal-separators-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers

Answer (score 0):

If You have generated EF mapping using database first. You should be concerned about EntityFramework..

EF maps SQL column type `float` into C# type `double` not float

see: [SqlClient for Entity FrameworkTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: In that case, `Loss` (from the data object) would be a `double`, when it's assigned `loss` from the controller (`float`) it'd be converted to a `double` for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as string and try like this while saving in entity framework:

```
var amount = decimal.Parse(InvoiceAmount, NumberStyles.Any);
```