# ViewData.ModelState.IsValid is false because Mvc can't parse value which has separated hundreds and thousands with commas

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I have fields of type `int?`.

On view i use jquery plugin which separate textBox value with commas like this : `3,463,436` = `3463436` - it's must be `int` value.

But on Form subbmit i get error "The value '3,463,436' is not valid for Maximum Contiguous."

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC one option is to implement a custom `ModelBinder` that strips out commas from the submitted values. I.e. implement a subclass of `DefaultModelBinder`

Here is how to do it for the decimal separator for the `decimal` data type:

[How to set decimal separators in ASP.NET MVC controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793459/how-to-set-decimal-separators-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers/5117441#5117441)

You will have to something similar for the thousands separator for the `int` data type.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than stripping out commas is to use .NET's built in NumberStyles parsing.

```
public class MyBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var v = ((string[])bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).RawValue)[0];
        int outPut;
        if (int.TryParse(v, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out outPut))
           return outPut;
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}

ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int), new MyBinder());
```