# asp.net core model binding for one property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a complex type

```
public class Model 
{
    public double D2 { get; set; }
}
```

And I receive this type inside action

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public string Post(Model model)
{
    return "";
}
```

Users want to have ability to type numbers with . (point) and , (comma) decimal separators, for example 234.245 and 234,245 are valid decimal types. But framework can't convert this numbers correctly.  Is there a way to "catch" the binding for doubles to have ability to normalize symbols before converting to double?

Comment: not sure if this works in `.net-core` http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

Comment: You always can write custom ModelBinder, but I sovle same situation by replacing commas by dots on client side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set decimal separators in ASP.NET MVC controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793459/how-to-set-decimal-separators-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers/5117441).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a way. Grab `d2` as `string` and then replace `.` to `,` and convert into `double` or whatever you want. For example:

```
public string Post(string d2)
{
    var model = new Model(){ D2 = Convert.ToDouble(d2.Replace(".", ",")) } 
    return "";
}
```

If you don't like this way make custom setter in `Model` by almost the same way