# Decimal value losing it's separator when reaches object setter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a form with a decimal field for a currency input.

This is what my HTML looks

```
<input asp-for="Valor" class="form-control" required autocomplete="Valor" type="number" step=".01" min="0.01" autofocus />
```

When i submit the form the field have the correct value:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETtmp.png

But when it reaches the **set** method of the object on the backend it's without the decimal separator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL2EC.png

what could i do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set decimal separators in ASP.NET MVC controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793459/how-to-set-decimal-separators-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers)

Comment: Yes i just needed to define in the culture on Startup.cs

` CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";  `