# How can I get the client side date and currency formats?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display dates and currency amounts in my users chosen format.
How can I retrive this from the client machine?

Alternatively, is there some other way to format dates/currency correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser exposes it's locale: You can retrieve it by using `** Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture**`

read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) and [here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx)

You can overwrite their Culture with a culture of your chosing (if the select another language from a menu perhaps)

to format the date time, and string read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx)

Watch out, setting a culture happens very soon in a page cycle, if you set it to late, the resource files will be those of a previous selected Culture.

To set the Culture early in the cycle you can create a basepage (that inherits ViewPage){}

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NerdDinner.Views
{
    public class NerdDinnerViewPage<T> : ViewPage<T> where T : class
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            base.InitializeCulture();

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="NerdDinner.Views.NerdDinnerViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel>" %>
```

here is the full example, but I copied the code for easyness: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760258/how-to-globalize-asp-net-mvc-views-decimal-separators-in-particular)

another approach is using the global asax which can be found [here](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture requires UICulture="auto" Culture="auto" in the view's page declaration.

eg
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" UICulture="auto" Culture="auto" %>

Answer (score 0):

In order to select a useful default for the .NET tools at your disposal (such as CultureInfo), my recommendation (in a web scenario) would be to parse the HTTP user agent string, as in the examples provided [here](http://www.useragents.org/useragent.asp). But in addition, the user should be able to override the default, and you ought to save the user's choice in a cookie and, if applicable, user options.

Comment: in mvc you can get the current culture as described in my answer. This is the same as you said, but already parsed for you

Comment: OK, I can see that. .NET MVC magic :). It might still help to remember where the data comes from.

Comment: absolutely very true, understanding what happens and how is 90% of all the magic that is IT :)