# Redirect user to page if request is from a certain IP range

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

In my Global.asax.cs file, I created a Session_Start method:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the incoming user's IP address.
    var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

    if (Helpers.RedirectHelpers.IpIsWithinBoliviaRange(ip))
    {
        //Render the bolivia page.
    }
    else
    {
        //Render the regular layout page.
    }
}
```

Assuming the code in the `IpIsWithinBoliviaRange()` method is already coded and working, how do I redirect the request so the user transparently sees a page I coded up?

Here is a snapshot of the solution so you can get a better picture:

[image]

The contents of _Layout.cshtml is what you would expect, nothing out of the ordinary.

On the _BoliviaLayout.cshtml file I've done something different:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>BOLIVIA PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I *render* this page if someone coming in from Bolivia visits the site? What do I need to do to invoke the rendering of this "view"?

Comment: Why not try a different more 'multi language' approach?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671992/how-do-you-handle-static-list-internationalization-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in the `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = Helpers.RedirectHelpers.IpIsWithinBoliviaRange(Request.UserHostAddress) ? "~/Views/Shared/_BoliviaLayout.cshtml" : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```